# How to add to a Git repository changes, that were done to files manually on server?

Tags: git

**The setup:**
local git repositories connected to a bare repository on a remote server. Changes pushed and pulled from and to the remote repository by several devs. A post update hook added on server, which updates the working tree, once something gets pushed to the bare repository on the server.

```
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/working/tree

git checkout -f
```

**The problem:**
changes were done via FTP directly in the files on server, without having the changes tracked on none of the local repositories, nor server bare repository. As i understand, if anything gets pushed from local rep onto server rep, the changes done directly on the server will get lost.

How can the manually done changes get tracked by Git now in order not to lose them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to do a checkout, then do a comparison in order to determine what files have changed, then add them into the repository by doing a commit and push. And then make the directories read-only to prevent this kind of thing happening in the future.

Comment: Could you explain more in details what exactly you mean by doing checkout? Also, doing a comparison in what way (an other program, but not Git comparison, right?)? As for directory and file permissions - i agree, it would help prevent from doing similar mistake again.

Comment: What i thought of, is to `scp` the files from server and throw them into the folder where my local git tracked files are. In this way git should indicate any changes upon `git status`. Is that an option?

Comment: I've found a solution, though i am not sure it is the same you suggested. What i did is - `scp` all the files from Git tracked directory from server to my local machine. Then i replaced local repository files with the ones `scp`-ed from server. Then `git status`. It showed me basically all the files as modified, as their timestamps were changed due to zippping and transfer. Then i did `git add -A`. This took all the files away from the list of staged files and left only the ones with real differences in content (not date only). Then i did `git commit` and `git push`. Seems solved.